# Excel VBA Macro Run time 53 file not found

Tags: excel, vba, file, file-not-found, filesystemobject

I created a macro to rename files, but received this error:

> Run-time error 53 File not found

But if I keep my cursor, it picks my location path correctly
"Name folder & Curname As folder & Newname"

```
Sub getname()
    Dim folder As String
    mfolder = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 2).Value
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 3
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(mfolder)
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value = objFile.Name
        i = i + 1
    Next objFile
End Sub
Sub reName()
    Dim mfolder As String
    Dim CurName As String
    Dim NewName As String
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 3
    mfolder = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 2).Value
    Do While Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Text <> "" And Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Text <> ""
       CurName = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Text
       NewName = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Text
       Name mfolder & CurName As mfolder & NewName
       i = i + 1
    Loop
    MsgBox ("Complete")
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have a path separator between the path and filename? Also, normal practice is to use `.Value` instead of `.Text`.

Comment: Before the Name command, use Dir to check if the file exists: `Dir(mfolder & CurName)`. It will return an empty string if the file does not exist. With that, you can pop up a msg box or write to a log file to determine the bad file name.

Comment: See - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/buildpath-method

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb I would always use early binding of Microsoft scripting runtime. This gives you access to intellisense and other benefits when using external references.

Tools >> references

[image]

Once added you import the object reference as follows.

```
dim fso as filesystemobject
set fso = new filesystemobject
```

this allows you to do things like this.

```
dim fldr as fldr
set fldr = fso.getfolder("c:\test_folder")
```

and iterating through files

```
dim fl as file
for each fl in fldr.files
    do something
next fl
```

It always helps me personally to see what options are available when using a new reference in VBA .

(when using late binding like you are you don't have this luxury)

[image]

and mainly renaming files

```
fldr.move("C:\test_folder2")
```

In my opinion you should store the path of the file

`objFile.path` not `objFile.Name`

this would store something like `C:\test\test.text`

so fix with getting the list of files

```
Function list_files():

' log all files

Dim fso As filesystemobject
Set fso = New filesystemobject
Dim fldr As fldr
Set fldr = fso.getfolder("c:\test_folder")
Dim fl as file
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("sheet1")
Dim i As Integer
i = 2

    For Each fl In fldr.Files
        ws.Cells(i, 1) = fl.Path
    Next fl

End Function
```

and renaming

```
Function rename_files():

' log all files

Dim fso As filesystemobject
Set fso = New filesystemobject
Dim fl As file
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("sheet1")
Dim lr As Integer

lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For x = 2 To lr
        If ws.Cells(x, 2) <> "" Then
            Set fl = fso.getfile(ws.Cells(x, 1))
            fl.Move (ws.Cells(x, 2))
        End If
    Next x

End Function
```

---

Something else to note is that when iterating through cells its always best practice to use something along the lines of this.

```
dim ws as worksheet
set ws = worksheets("Sheet1") ' get the worksheet

dim lr as integer  ' create lr interger reference
lr = ws.cells(rows.count,1).end(xlup).row

for x = 2 to lr
    'do something
next x
```

lets break down whats happening here.

### `ws.cells(rows.count,1).end(xlup).row`

`ws`                     in the worksheet

`cells`                  in the cells

`rows.count`             get the last row

`1`                      in column one

so....

`ws.cells(rows.count,1)` is referencing ALL cells in column 1

then....

`.end(xlup)`             goes upwards to where the data starts (or the blank lines end)

`row`                    logs the row number

Then when you do your for loop you are not checking for the empty cells as you already know where it is.

```
for x = 2 to lr 'the last row in the data with data in it.
    if ws.cells(x,2) <> "" then
        'do something because column 1 and 2 both have no value in the cell
    end if
next x
```

hope this helps somewhat